# How are sql views optimized

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, view

I know that a VIEW is just a stored SELECT query that is run whenever it is queried. That VIEW will have a list of where clauses on the original select. However, we may also query the VIEW as a normal table. When we query a VIEW in such a way, and we add certain where clauses in that query, is the final select that actually runs, optimized to include the where clauses that are specified in the query over the VIEW ? Or does the view first execute, and then the query over the VIEW execute thus causing rows constituted in the VIEW to get processed twice?

Comment: In general, optimization strategies depend on the database.  This is one place in particular that is highly database-dependent.  You should start by learning about execution plans, cached execution plans, and the optimization strategies for the database you are using.

Comment: School work? How views are implemented depends on the dbms.

Comment: The database I'm concerned about is Oracle 11g. Frankly I dont know to interpret execution plans as yet. But logically, it felt only perfectly reasonable to me, to include the additional where clauses of the query over the view, with the where clauses of the view and run the whole query just once. Is it not the case with major databases, or with Oracle in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The larger DBMSs (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL and PostgreSQL) will combine the filtering criteria of the view and your query.

Here is one easy way to tell that doesn't require DBA access or knowledge.

Create a view on a very large table. Hit the performance with some manipulation of some of the fields:

```
create view Test as
select  A, B, C, Mod( A, B ) as Dummy1, Mod( A, C ) as Dummy1, etc.
from    TableWithLotsAndLotsOfRows
where   Mod( A, B ) > 0 or Mod( A, C ) > 0;
```

Perform an open query on the view:

```
select * from Test;
```

There should be a meaningful pause before you see any result. Hopefully, it will be several minutes -- the longer the better (up to a point!).

Now filter the view query using criteria that limit the result set to one or very few rows:

```
select * from Test where ID = 123456;
```

You should get a result immediately (assuming you would get an immediate result if you directly queried the table).

That shows that the view query is not being executed *then* the query filtering performed. If it had, the result could not have been faster.

Note: depending on the system, you may have to clear the cache between queries to get meaningful results. A quick way is to break the connection and reconnect. Then you don't have to bother your DBA on how to clear cache. He will get very upset with you if he doesn't know the answer.... ;-)

Comment: Yeah..this adroit solution worked well. Looks like VIEWS are indeed getting optimized to include all WHERE clauses before being run. Tested for Oracle 11g. However, official explanations by major database vendors on how views are executed behind the scenes should be very helpful. Its strange that there is no literature on that.

Comment: Yes. I use views a LOT and would be very interested in an internals "view" of views (hee-hee). Surely this documentation exists. Someone on the inside just has to publish it.

Comment: Oracle has very good documentation on query optimisation, you just have to know where to look. This particular feature, predicate pushing, is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_transform.htm#TGSQL210 For more information, this Database SQL Tuning Guide is what you want.